# beginner and cpp class

Tags: c++

I'm using the code under "Constructors and destructors" [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

Basically, i would like to combine it with the pointer construction under 
"Pointers to classes" (a little below) which i find really neat.

Now this works:

```
int main () {
   CRectangle * prect;     //l2
   CRectangle rect (3,4);  //l3
   prect = &rect;          //l4
   cout << "rect area: " << (*prect).area() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

My questions is, can we replace l2-l4 by a more elegant method 
not requiring the creation of rect on line 3?

Comment: CRectangle *prect = new CRectangle(3,4);

Comment: `prect->area()` - a bit less typing and fewer brackets. Don't forget to `delete` it if you use Martol1ni's method too. Alternatively, use a smart pointer.

Comment: @Martol1ni This is probably what OP was looking for, although being a beginner used a wrong expression: there's nothing elegant in using unguarded dynamic allocation.

Comment: Martol1ni exactly what i wanted to see. @chris: question, there is a function called :~CRectangle() in the example i linked to. Would it not take care of destruction automatically? [may be a very naive question]

Comment: @user189035, you need to free the memory taken by allocating memory for the object pointed to by the pointer. You should `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]`what you `new[]`.

Comment: @user189035: when you create an object with `new`, that tells the program you need this object to violate scoping rules, and so the program will not automatically call the destructor until you tell it to, using the `delete` keyword.

Comment: @user189035 ~CRectangle() is the destructor of that class. Is it called as soon you call delete on a heap-allocated object or as soon a stack-allocated object runs out of scope. The destructor is meant to clean up "mess" the object produced; not the callee. Those mess might be other objects allocated on heap or simply things the object changed and which should get reverted.

Comment: @chris: You should never, ever `delete` or `new[]` or `delete[]` anything. Use Standard class.

Comment: @DeadMG, of course, unless you're learning. A smart pointer is definitely better, which is why I mentioned it in my first comment.

Comment: @chris: No, *especially* when you're learning.

Comment: @DeadMG, I think you misunderstood. I mean learning about pointers at a lower level, so you're familiar with how they work. Of course it's great to use smart pointers, but sometime you're going to have to know.

Comment: @chris: Yeah- you're going to have to know approximately *years after you can use them*. How many years did you know addition before you saw the implementation of a full adder?

Comment: @DeadMG, it's a good example, but not in line with the specifics of how code dealing with pointers works. I'll give it to you though, because using `new` definitely doesn't add any value. I was talking about pointers more as in their use in standard container algorithms etc without realizing it, but that's a whole different use, nothing to do with this, so I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an object without requiring any automatic variables (such as `rect` in your code above) you must use the `new` operator. Objects created with the `new` operator are stored in the *free store*, and the `new` expression evaluates into a pointer to the newly created object.

Now, one could go on and say, `new` operator is the answer and that's it, but it's actually not: it does not answer the question of replacing those couple of lines with a more elegant solution, because it wouldn't be one.

The rest of this answer goes on a tangent of how `new` could be used.

Unlike automatic objects, objects stored in the free store are not automatically destructed, but rather their life-time and destruction is controlled by the `delete` operator (you should delete objects you no longer need to free resources). To ensure destruction, you should always store the pointer from a `new` expression into what's called a *smart pointer*. A good, simple rule that carries one far: *use the `new` operator only inside a smart pointer constructor* (unless you know what you're doing).

There are several smart pointers in C++11, while earlier versions of the standard only defined one, the `auto_ptr`. Perhaps due to it's quirks, or simply because it got a replacement, it's actually deprecated in C++11, and shouldn't probably be used in new code, at least not in C++11 (now, this is an opinion).

An example of smart pointer use:

```
boost::shared_ptr<CRectangle> shared_rect(new CRectange(3, 4));
std::unique_ptr<CRectangle> rect(new CRectangle(3, 4)); // C++11 only

// use smart pointers like like regular pointers; indirection through * or ->
// i.e. (*rect).area() or rect->area()
```

Comment: @eq: thanks for the recommendation. I will look unto auto_ptr

Comment: Actually, you don't even need `new`, you can (and actually should) use [`make_shared`](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html) (or `C++11`'s [`std`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) equivalent). For `unique_ptr`, there is no `std` version, but you can grab one [here](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/). Using these are better for exception safety (and efficiency in allocation for `shared_ptr`).

Comment: -1 lots of small incorrectnesses, plus teaching the Wrong Thing for the OP

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I agree on the (possibility of) incorrectnesses, but not on the Wrong Thing. OP has one explicit question that can be answered "no" (an opinion, clarified it after hiding it earlier). There might be a lot of babbling around, but sometimes you don't know what to ask because you don't know what to ask (or it's interesting to learn about something to look up).

Answer (score 3):

I like @eq-'s answer as well, but in addition to dynamic memory allocation, you can also try placement new. (When I say "try", I don't mean this is the way to do things, but more like this is more food for thought. I am not trying to lead you to a maze of twisty little passages, all alike.)

```
char mem[sizeof(CRectangle)] alignas(CRectangle);
CRectangle *prect = new (mem) CRectangle(3, 4); // construct
std::cout
    << "rect area: " << prect->area()
    << std::endl;
prect->~CRectangle();                           // destruct
```

You would typically use placement new when working with a custom allocator. A custom allocator could be used for various reasons, but in my work it is typically for pre-allocation strategies (like a pool allocator, or an embedded system with strict memory provisioning). In this case, the placement new is being used to initialize memory that has automatic storage class. Like your original `rect` object, the memory for the object becomes invalid when the code falls out of scope. However, the `CRectangle` constructor may perform initializations that require clean up, so there is an explicit call to the destructor before the memory falls out of scope.

Note, you cannot use `auto_ptr` for `prect`, because calling delete on the pointer would be undefined (since the memory was not dynamically created). You could use `shared_ptr` if you pass in a custom deleter to the constructor. You could use `unique_ptr` if you pass in a custom deleter in the second template parameter. The custom deleter simply makes an explicit call to the destructor so that the smart pointers do the work of cleaning up automatically when the code falls out of scope.

```
template <typename T>
struct placement_delete {
    void operator () (T *t) const { t->~T(); }
};

char mem2[2][sizeof(CRectangle) alignas(CRectangle);
std::shared_ptr<CRectangle>
    sprect(new (mem2[0]) CRectangle(2, 3), placement_delete<CRectangle>());
std::unique_ptr< CRectangle, placement_delete<CRectangle> >
    uprect(new (mem2[1]) CRectangle(3, 4));
```

The `new` call may throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception. Since it is uncaught, your program will terminate immediately after the exception is thrown with an error result. If you want to gracefully deal with exceptions, you use `try` and `catch` blocks.

```
CRectangle *prect;
try {
    prect = new (mem) CRectangle(3, 4);
} catch (std::bad_alloc) {
    // do something about it?
    abort();
}
```

For learning, `abort` is okay. It gets you practicing catching exceptions, but lets you quickly pinpoint the location of the problem when analyzing the error state left behind as the result of the `abort`. (On UNIX, this is typically a core file.)

Comment: placement new is not for beginners, and the reason is because most people, including you (and usually myself), use it wrong.  In this case, you completely forgot alignment.

Comment: @MooingDuck, +1. Thanks, alignment is fixed.

Comment: Strictly speaking that doesn't guarantee the alignment is correct. You have to use `aligned_storage` (or C++11's `alignas`). That said, there's really no reason to be using placement new here; it's a neat bit of information, sure, but with the problems the questioner is currently dealing with, it's just too advanced.

Comment: I realize that placement new is not really a beginner's topic, but one could say the same thing about `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, and exception handling. I felt this explanation was closer to the OP's code in that the memory has the same automatic storage class as the OP's `rect` object.

Comment: @user315052: Those things are black boxes that simply must be learned. Placement-new is neither a black box nor necessary nor applicable.

Comment: @GManNickG: I always hated it in school when the teacher would tell me to ignore things I read in the documentation. A C++ reference on `new` will mention placement new. An STL reference will talk about all the constructors of `shared_ptr` and template arguments of `unique_ptr`. Ignoring the more complicated aspects of the feature does not really make the feature any less advanced.

Comment: @user315052: Like it or not, that's how learning works. You learned to add before you learned how addition can be defined, it's more practical.

Answer (score 0):

How about this then?

```
int main () {
   CRectangle rect (3,4); // on stack
   cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

or if you *must* have `prect`:

```
int main () {
   CRectangle rect (3,4); // still on stack
   CRectangle * prect = &rect; // simple alias
   cout << "rect area: " << prect->area() << endl; // same as (*prect).area()
   return 0;
}
```

But at least in your simple code `prect` is redundant.

Normally one would expect to see some `new CRectangle()` (or a class derived from `CRectangle`, allocated on the heap) assigned to `prect` upon creation or later. But it's not very clear what you intend to do. But since in your example `prect` is merely an alias for `rect`, why not use `rect` directly (my first piece of code)?

---

Using heap:

```
int main () {
   CRectangle* prect = new CRectangle(3,4); // using heap
   // new will throw if out of memory, so no check for null pointer needed here
   cout << "rect area: " << prect->area() << endl; // same as (*prect).area()
   delete prect; // free the memory - needed because it's not a stack object
   return 0;
}
```

The STL has `std::auto_ptr` now superseded by `std::unique_ptr` (in C++11) as mentioned by Mooing Duck in a comment. Since this "smart pointer" acts as a container class on the stack for the pointer of our class which is on the heap, it will also do the cleanup

```
int main () {
   try
   {
     std::auto_ptr<CRectangle> prect(new CRectangle(3,4)); // using heap, via smart ptr
     // new will throw if out of memory, so no check for null pointer needed here
     cout << "rect area: " << prect->area() << endl; // same as (*prect).area()
   }
   catch(exception& e)
   {
     cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The main difference between `auto_ptr` and `unique_ptr` would be their semantics w.r.t. ownership. You can get an overview on the Wikipedia page on [Smart Pointers](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: yes, i know it is redundant. I'm trying to see what can and can't be done with pointers & classes (this is a pedagogical example).

Comment: ok, if it helps with managing the answers (although this is self learning, no homework proper).

Comment: @DeadMG: because it makes it less readable. But I hope my edit suits you better though introducing too many concepts at once isn't exactly helpful ...

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: That's blatantly untrue. For decades, C++ was taught with books that taught bad coding style, and it got us into a bloody mess. Teach the right style right from the start. Modern C++ supports that. Meanwhile, I downvote.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: You've only made it *worse*. I wish I could downvote your answer *again*.

Comment: @DeadMG: please explain your criticism then instead of ranting. I'm open to criticism if well-placed and constructive. Thanks.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Well, you made absolutely no efforts whatsoever to ensure that the memory was cleaned up. You "caught an exception" but did nothing useful with it.

Comment: @MooingDuck: it's C++11 but certainly worth mentioning. Thanks.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I still give my upvote for a well formatted, clearly and simply explained answer. Kudos to you, sir.

Comment: @DeadMG: better now? As for the memory cleanup: please enlighten me (for this exact example) how a leak was still possible? `cout` is designed to do the type-checking at compile time ... so if the `new` didn't throw the `delete` should have been reached. If the `new` threw, no memory would have been allocated. But the exception handling could have been neater, admittedly.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: I believe his point is that in general, exception safety should be taught.  In this case, what if `prect->area()` or `operator<<` threw an exception?  That's why `unique_ptr` is to be promoted.